# Extension Method for Conversion

Tags: c#, extension-methods

let's assume i have a class like below :

```
public class PhysicalMemory 
{ 
    public string Localtion { get; internal set; } 
    public ulong Capacity { get; internal set; } 
    public string Manufacturer { get; internal set; } 
    public string Part_Number { get; internal set; } 
    public string Serial_Number { get; internal set; } 
    public uint Speed { get; internal set; }
}
```

I need an extension method to convert my Capacity from bytes to KBytes , MBytes and ..... if user wanted to , for example:

```
PhysicalMemory phM = New PhysicalMemory();
ulong capacity_in_bytes = phM.Capacity;

ulong capacity_in_KB = phM.Capacity.ToKBytes();
ulong capacity_in_MB = phM.Capacity.ToMBytes();
```

Comment: Did these answers solve your problem?

Comment: Please don't leave post unattended. Remember to mark the answer whichever convinced you or solved your problem. Saying this specifically because you are new here.

Answer (score 3):

It does not make sense to have extension methods for this purpose. Even if it is possible to write extension method as shown by others here, you really need to stay away from doing so. If you write one, it would just be a method that converts X `ulong` to Y `ulong`.

Best you can do here is just to add respective properties or methods for converting capacity. I would prefer just having readonly properties. And that's even simpler than to have separate extension methods.

```
public class PhysicalMemory 
{ 
    public ulong Capacity { get; internal set; } 
    public ulong CapacityMB { get { return Capacity / (1024 * 1024); } } 
    public ulong CapacityKB { get { return Capacity / 1024; } } 
}
```

Comment: Interesting way :) didn't think of it

Answer (score 2):

```
public static class ULongExtensions
{
    public static ulong ToKBytes(this ulong memory)
    {
        return memory / 1024;
    }

    public static ulong ToMByptes(this ulong memory)
    {
        return memory.ToKBytes() / 1024;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank @fubo :) A bit of balance this morning :)

Answer (score 0):

If you've created the class `PhysicalMemory` there is no point in creating Extension Methods. These are used to extend classes that you are not able to modify (for one reason or another).

There is also no point in storing MB values in `ulong`. This way you don't differentiate between `2.1 MB` and `2.2 MB`. I don't think you want this behavior, do it is better to go with `decimal` or `double`

However, you can do it this way:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static decimal ToKBytes(this ulong value)
    {
        return value / (decimal)1024;
    }

    public static decimal ToMBytes(this ulong value)
    {
        return value / ((decimal)1024 * 1024);
    }
}
```

I would highly suggest not to extend `ulong` type with these methods. It doesn't make any sense for me. Either Create some conversion Module or Add the methods to your class (Maybe as Properties)